# Manually Link Stored Procedure To LINQ

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql, stored-procedures

I have a Stored Procedure that returns a dynamic result set based on a temporary table.  My project uses LINQ for Data Access, but I can't incorporate LINQ with this Stored Procedure because it has a dynamic "shape" (I can't say before hand which columns will come back or how many there will be), so LINQ can't generate at design time an object that can hold the results.

I am trying to integrate the stored procedure the old fashioned was, using SQLDataAdapter and such, but I was hoping that I could still tie into LINQ so that I don't need to manage a separate transaction mechanism as that would be a disaster.

Is this possible?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One best practice is that a stored procedure should never be coded such that it gives different columns in a result set based on inputs.

It sounds like your design is causing the single stored proc to try and do too many things.  I'd highly suggest you change this.

Comment: The stored procedure is trying to return a grid.  The columns of the grid are different years, but we don't know ahead of time what years will be returned for what data, so that is why we have a dynamic number of columns.  Previously we pulled all of the data back and then made business logic decisions as to what columns where to display, but this led to performance issues.  Can anyone suggest an alternative approach?

Answer (score 1):

First - you aren't using "LINQ" for data access.  My guess is you are using Entity Framework for data access.  If you are, it depends on which version of EF you are using.

New in Entity Framework 4 is shaping data from a stored proc.  For step-by-step instructions, see this blog post:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nihitk/archive/2010/04/23/ado-net-entity-designer-in-vs-2010-stored-procedure-return-type-shape-sensing.aspx

If you are using Entity Framework 1, which comes with .NET 3.5, then no EF does not have the ability to sense the shape of the stored proc data.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I looked at the page and it looks like you have to make manual changes as the stored procedure schema changes.   The problem in my situation is that the SP changes dynamically based on each call.

Comment: @skaz:  Can you post more info? Then we can help you make a better design or development decision.

Comment: Since the OP tagged the question as LINQ to SQL, I'm betting they are using LINQ to SQL for data access.